# AutoCompleteTextView does not show drop down

Tags: android, android-widget, autocompletetextview

I have a button (setButton), and immediately upon pressing the button, I want my modified AutoCompleteTextView to show the dropdown menu

I have two classes

AutoCompleteTextViewTest1Activity.class

```
package com.autocompletetextviewtest1;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;


public class AutoCompleteTextViewTest1Activity extends Activity {
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2;
private InstantAutoComplete actv;
private String[] countries2 ={"Taiwan", "China", "S. Korea", "USA", "Japan", "Russia"};
private String[] countries={};
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, countries);
adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, countries2);
actv = (InstantAutoComplete)findViewById(R.id.actv);
actv.setAdapter(adapter1);

Button setButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.setButton);
Button clearButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.clearButton);

setButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
public void onClick(View v){
actv.setAdapter(adapter2);
actv.requestFocus();
}
});

clearButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
public void onClick(View v){
actv.setAdapter(adapter1);
        }
});
}
}
```

And

InstantAutoComplete.class

```
package com.autocompletetextviewtest1;

import android.content.Context;   
import android.graphics.Rect; 
import android.util.AttributeSet; 
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView; 

public class InstantAutoComplete extends AutoCompleteTextView { 

public InstantAutoComplete(Context context) { 
super(context); 
} 

public InstantAutoComplete(Context arg0, AttributeSet arg1) { 
super(arg0, arg1); 
} 

public InstantAutoComplete(Context arg0, AttributeSet arg1, int arg2) { 
super(arg0, arg1, arg2); 
} 

@Override 
public boolean enoughToFilter() { 
return true; 
} 

@Override 
protected void onFocusChanged(boolean focused, int direction, 
Rect previouslyFocusedRect) { 
super.onFocusChanged(focused, direction, previouslyFocusedRect); 
if (focused) { 
performFiltering(getText(), 0); 
showDropDown(); 

} 
} 

}
```

But my AutoCompleteTextView does not show the dropdown menu UPON pressing the setButton.  What can I do?  Thanks!

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE!!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12854336/autocompletetextview-backed-by-cursorloader

Answer (score 0):

Try calling actv.invalidate() inside setButton onClick to refresh the view with newly updated adapter.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me. Note that I have log's at appropriate places to check if my webservice call, and its return value. This is crucial to the working of the autocomplete. In your case you may need to remove the webservice call and populate the adapter yourself with hardcoded values.

Initialize in onCreate

```
fromAutoComplete = new AutoComplete(this, R.layout.autocomplete_list_item);
fromAutoComplete.setNotifyOnChange(true);
fromAddress = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.fromAddress);
fromAddress.setAdapter(fromAutoComplete);
fromAddress.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

The AutoComplete adapter that checks for your characters and calls the webservice over and over again, to show in the drop down.

> > Please note,
> >
> > 1. this api needs a google api key, which you need generate for yourself. Also dont forget to enable Location API's for your key. Without this it **wont** work.
> > 2. the placing of the variables in the webservice call matter (for some crazy reason). the sensor variable at the end worked for me. Feel free to test it on fiddler or chrome from your logcat.

```
public AutoComplete(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return resultList.size();
}

@Override
public String getItem(int index) {
    return resultList.get(index);
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    Filter filter = new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
            if (constraint != null) {
                // Retrieve the autocomplete results.
                resultList = autocomplete(constraint.toString());

                // Assign the data to the FilterResults
                filterResults.values = resultList;
                filterResults.count = resultList.size();
            }
            return filterResults;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else {
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            }
        }
    };
    return filter;
}

private ArrayList<String> autocomplete(String input) {
    ArrayList<String> resultList = null;

    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    StringBuilder jsonResults = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(PLACES_API_BASE + TYPE_AUTOCOMPLETE + OUT_JSON);
        sb.append("?key=" + API_KEY+"&sensor=false");
        sb.append("&components=country:in");
        sb.append("&input=" + URLEncoder.encode(input, "utf8"));
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Calling "+sb.toString()) ;

        URL url = new URL(sb.toString());
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());

        // Load the results into a StringBuilder
        int read;
        char[] buff = new char[1024];
        while ((read = in.read(buff)) != -1) {
            jsonResults.append(buff, 0, read);
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error processing Places API URL", e);
        return resultList;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error connecting to Places API", e);
        return resultList;
    } finally {
        if (conn != null) {
            conn.disconnect();
        }
    }

    try {
        // Create a JSON object hierarchy from the results
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonResults.toString());
        JSONArray predsJsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("predictions");

        // Extract the Place descriptions from the results
        resultList = new ArrayList<String>(predsJsonArray.length());
        for (int i = 0; i < predsJsonArray.length(); i++) {
            resultList.add(predsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("description"));
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Cannot process JSON results", e);
    }

    Log.d(LOG_TAG, resultList.size() + " in total returned.") ;

    return resultList;
}
```

On Selecting a item from drop down text

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
    Double latitude, longitude;
    ArrayList<String> resultList = null;
    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    StringBuilder jsonResults = new StringBuilder();
    String str = (String) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position);
    try {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(
                "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?" + "address="
                        + URLEncoder.encode(str, "utf-8") + "&sensor=true");

        URL url = new URL(sb.toString());
        Log.d("Taxeeta", url.toString() + " Called");
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());

        // Load the results into a StringBuilder
        int read;
        char[] buff = new char[1024];
        while ((read = in.read(buff)) != -1) {
            jsonResults.append(buff, 0, read);
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        Log.e("Taxeeta", "Error processing Places API URL", e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("Taxeeta", "Error connecting to Places API", e);
    } finally {
        if (conn != null) {
            conn.disconnect();
        }
    }

    try {
        // Create a JSON object hierarchy from the results
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonResults.toString());
        JSONObject location = ((JSONObject) jsonObj.getJSONArray("results").get(0))
                .getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location");
        latitude = location.optDouble("lat");
        longitude = location.optDouble("lng");
        Log.d("Taxeeta", "Received Latitude " + latitude + ": Longitude" + longitude);
        if (view.getId() == fromAddress.getId()) {
            source = new GeoPoint((int) (latitude * 1E6), (int) (longitude * 1E6));
            Log.d("Taxeeta", "Source Done");
        } else {
            destination = new GeoPoint((int) (latitude * 1E6), (int) (longitude * 1E6));
            Log.d("Taxeeta", "Destination Done");
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("Taxeeta", "Cannot process JSON results", e);
    }
}
```